# How do I insert a breakpoint so that edebug starts only when that point is reached

Tags: edebug

I want to instrument a function so that edebug gets control when that point is reached.  I can insert `(edebug)` in the code, however, unless the function is instrumented with edebug (`C-u M-S-x`), that will be interpreted as `(debug)`, which I don't want.  But if the function is instrumented with edebug, then a break occurs everytime the function is called, not just when the particular point in the function is reached.  I only want the break to occur (and get control with edebug) when a particular place in the function is reached.

Comment: `c` the first time to get to your breakpoint; `g` thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

Customize the user option <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `edebug-initial-mode` or use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edebug-set-initial-mode`<sup>1</sup> to set the value `go` instead of the default `step`.

In the absence of relevant breakpoints, an instrumented function will now simply run to completion without interruption.

Note that you can set breakpoints in an instrumented function with `M-x edebug-set-breakpoint` or `M-x edebug-set-conditional-breakpoint`, or using the <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> bindings, without the debugger being active at the time.

---

<sup>1</sup> See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Edebug Execution Modes` for the valid options.

In `emacs-lisp-mode` buffers (but not in the `*scratch*` buffer's `lisp-interaction-mode`, which seems like a bug) you also have the following GUD-style bindings available when edebug has been loaded:

```
C-x C-a C-c   edebug-go-mode
C-x C-a C-s   edebug-step-mode
C-x C-a C-n   edebug-next-mode
C-x C-a C-l   edebug-where
```

As well as this non-GUD binding under the same prefix:

```
C-x C-a RET   edebug-set-initial-mode
```

Hence:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> -- change initial mode to `go`.
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> -- change initial mode to `step`.